# How to display alert when option from form is selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form that has 32 options to pick from with different categories hence the optgroup tags. I need to make it so that when I click on the form and then on the option, then the value of the option will be displayed. The issue is that if I click on an option that is already choosen for that form, the alert doesn't appear. I need to be able to click on the default option and have it store my data in a javascript variable and I am scared that my default choice won't be stored unless I see that the alert has been triggered which tells me the value of the variable. I have tried a few different event listeners to no avail. This is my HTML code snippet:

```
    <form>
      <label for="teams"> C1</label>
      <select name="teams" id="userInput" onchange="team()">
        <optgroup label ="Foo">
          <option value="Foa">Fooa</option>
          <option value="Fob">Foob</option>
          <option value="Foc">Fooc</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
      </form>
      <form>
```

This is in a separate JS file:

```
function team(){
  let inputy = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  alert(inputy);
}
```

I tried to have an alert when a form option was selected. I tried using the `onlick()` event, but it would display the option that is in the box by default and not what I selected.

Comment: What is your question? That code should work.

Comment: I am getting the correct values

Comment: @Andy The issue is that when I select the same option that is the default option, the alarm doesn't trigger. For example, Fooa would already be selected by default in the form but when I click on the form and select is again, the alarm doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use : **select.options[select.selectedIndex]**
try below code,

```
<html>
   <body>

    <form>
      <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label><br>
      <select id="cars" onchange="showAlert()">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
       </select>
    </form> 

  <script>
  function showAlert() {
    var select = document.getElementById("cars");
    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    alert("You have selected the option with value: " + 
    selectedOption.value + " and text: " + selectedOption.text);
  }
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your listener is on the `select` element you're essentially using [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) - attaching one listener to a parent element to catch events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM. Here you *can* use `click`.

Once a `click` event has been captured the handler needs to work out if the element that fired the event is an `option` element, and only run the rest of the code if it is. You can do that check with [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches). Opening the select won't fire the event, but subsequent clicks on the options will.

Note: in this example I've removed the inline JS to the JS file, and used [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which is considered better practice.

```js
// Cache the element, and add an event listener to it
const select = document.querySelector('#userInput');
select.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {

  // Check to see if the clicked element
  // is an option element, and then log/alert it
  if (e.target.matches('option')) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="teams"> C1</label>
  <select name="teams" id="userInput">
    <optgroup label="Foo">
      <option value="Foa">Fooa</option>
      <option value="Fob">Foob</option>
      <option value="Foc">Fooc</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</form>
```

Additional documentation

- [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)